# Need help in proving,In finite complement topology on a set $X$,the closed sets consist of $X$ itself and all finite subsets of $X$.

Tags: general-topology

This is an example from Munkre's Topology.

I need help in  proving,**In finite complement topology on a set $X$,the closed sets consist of $X$ itself and all finite subsets of $X$.**

I don't know how to begin this even.

thanks!

Comment: What are the open sets?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila:If $X$ is a toplological space with toplology $\mathfrak F$,we say that a subset $U$ of $X$ is an open set of $X$ if $U$ belongs to the collection $\mathfrak F$.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant to hint you towards asking yourself which sets are open, and therefore which sets are the complements of open sets. This will provide you with the answer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:in finite complement topology,singletons are closed,therefore the complement of singletons in  finite complement topology will be open?

Comment: It seems that you know all that you need to know in order to finish the proof. Just verify that every closed set is finite, and every finite set is closed. Depending on your definitions (or proven equivalent definitions) for closed sets and the cofinite topology, this is either trivial or just a simple exercise in verifying definitions. Good luck.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:I think the result follows from the very definition of finite complement topology,$\frak F_f$={$A \subset  X:A^{c} $ is finite,or $A^{c}= X$}.

Since $A \in \mathfrak F_f \implies A^{c}(closed)$ is either finite  or is whole of $X$.

Comment: Almost sounds like the very definition of the co-finite topology.  The co-finite sets, the empty set $\emptyset$, and $X$ itself are the open sets by definition.  Their complements, accordingly, are the closed sets.  $X$ is the complement of $\emptyset$, hence is closed (in addition to being also open).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finite complement topology means that an open subset is a subset whose complement is finite or is the empty subset. A closed subset is the complement of an open subset. Here by definition, the complement of an open subset is finite or $X$ if the open subset is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a generic closed subset $F$ and apply definitions.

Since $F$ is closed, it must be that $F^c$ is open (this is the definition of "closed" in any topology).

Since $F^c$ is open, it must be that $(F^c)^c$ is finite (this is what it means to be open in the finite complement topology).

Fortunately, $(F^c)^c = F$, so we just concluded that $F$ is finite.

Note that I've only shown that every closed set is finite. The wording of your question sounds as though you should also show that every finite set it closed, which is similar to what I've done here.

Comment: :You've shown that closed sets consist of all finite subets of $X$,but how can we show closed sets consist of $X$ itself also?

Comment: @PKStyles The empty set is open in every topology, so its complement (namely $X$) is closed. Please do not take offense, but it sounds as though you would benefit from reviewing the introductory definitions in Munkres regarding open and closed sets.

Comment: :i appreciate your comment,i come to know that $X$ & $\phi$ are both closed and open sets in $X$.